# Нужно вывести битовые данные числовых значений

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Нужно вывести битовые данные числовых значений из переменных.
Написал программу, она не выводит последний бит, не могу понять причину.
Делаю всё по заданию, нужно использовать операции побитовых сдвигов.

```
template<typename T>
void to_binary(T x)
{
    unsigned char* pb;
    pb = (unsigned char*)&x;
    size_t size_byte = sizeof(x) * 8;
    int *res = new int[size_byte];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            res[(i * 8) + j] = (pb[i] >> j) % 2;
    int b = 0;
    for (size_t i = size_byte - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << res[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int FourCel = 7;
    to_binary(FourCel);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы выводите все элементы массива `res`, кроме элемента с индексом `0`. Перепишите цикл вывода одним из следующих способов:

```
//Способ №1:
for (std::size_t i = size_byte; i > 0; i--) {
    std::cout << res[i - 1];
}

//Способ №2:
for (std::size_t i = size_byte - 1; i < std::size_t(-1); i--) {
    std::cout << res[i];
}

//Способ №3:
#include <cstddef>
...
for (std::ptrdiff_t i = size_byte - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    std::cout << res[i];
}

//Способ №4:
for (std::size_t i = size_byte; i-- > 0;) {
    std::cout << res[i];
}
```

Третий способ следует использовать с осторожностью. Если значение `size_byte - 1` больше чем `std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max()`, то цикл вывода будет работать неправильно.

[Есть мнение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623263/reverse-iteration-with-an-unsigned-loop-variable/3626468#3626468), что из предложенных способов четвёртый [наиболее предпочтителен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1184223#comment-2061885).

---

В функции `to_binary` вы выделяете память (`int *res = new int[size_byte];`), но нигде её не освобождаете. Память необходимо освободить.

А вообще, если ваша цель просто *вывести* последовательность битов, то в дополнительном массиве нет необходимости. [Пример](https://ideone.com/FrWPUa):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
void to_binary(T x)
{
    const unsigned char* byte = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&x + 1);

    for (std::size_t i = sizeof(x); i > 0; --i)
    {
        --byte;
        for (std::size_t j = CHAR_BIT; j > 0; --j)
            std::cout << ( (*byte >> (j - 1)) & 1u );
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: А как же самый [прикольный способ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3626468/13970074) `-->0`?)

Comment: а вы уверенны что const unsigned char* byte = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&x + 1) это правильно? может там скобочки потерялись по дороге? как бы судя по приоритету операций мы берем адрес с переменной Х и увеличиваем его на один и сохраняем в переменную byte, не выйдет так что мы не те данные выведем?

Comment: @Yakov, Перед циклом указатель `byte` указывает на байт, следующий непосредственно за последним байтом объекта `x`. В цикле мы сразу же уменьшаем `byte` на единицу. Теперь он указывает на последний байт объекта `x`. На следующей итерации цикла `byte` снова уменьшается на единицу и теперь указывает на предпоследний байт объекта `x` и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> i > 0
> ```

```
~i
```

Так цикл будет выполняться на одну итерацию больше (при 0).

Comment: Хитро. Однако, нужно следить, чтобы [integer conversion rank](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rank#note-1) у типа переменной `i` был не меньше чем у `int`. Иначе возможны [неприятные сюрпризы](https://ideone.com/IE2dxR).

Comment: @wololo, но ведь size_t не может быть меньше int'а?

Comment: Стандарт языка не требует, чтобы ранг `std::size_t` был не меньше ранга `int`'а. Впрочем не могу привести в качестве примера никакого реально существующего компилятора, имеющего ранг `std::size_t` меньше чем у `int`. Таким образом, с практической точки зрения ваше возражение справедливо, признаю. См.: [Difference between size_t and unsigned int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732319/difference-between-size-t-and-unsigned-int)

Comment: @wololo, ещё есть варианты написать `(size_t)~i` или `i !== ~0LL`.

Comment: Вариант с `(size_t)~i` сработает, а вот `i != 0LL` может [не сработать](https://ideone.com/pGLfcu). P.S. в своём ответе я не пытался перечислить все мыслимые способы ;)

Comment: @wololo, хм.. Логично.

Answer (score 0):

[EOF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/361068/eof)

правильно ответил, нужно в цикле изменить тип size_t на int и условие вывода изменить на i>=0

Comment: Для счётчика лучше использовать тип `std::size_t`, а не `int`, тем более если вы ему присваиваете `size_byte` типа `std::size_t`. А условие изменить на `-->0`, например